# Atbash Cipher in Rust

Tags: rust

So I'm working on an implementation of the Atbash Cipher for Rust - it is an exercise on exercism.io. I come from a little C experience and found my code to be rather round about and kind of tortured. Doing str and String manipulation in Rust is something I haven't really grokked yet. It seems like this would take up fewer lines of code in C.

Below is my code - am I going about this in the right way for Rust, or am I missing some important concept or way of minupulating the data? Is this as simple as it should be?

The exercise involves getting an input `&str` and outputting a `String`, with each character changed as per the atbash cipher, adding a space every 5 characters. Included is also a `decode` function. This all goes in a `lib.rs`.

```
// "Encipher" with the Atbash cipher.
pub fn encode(plain: &str) -> String {
    let mut coded: String = plain.to_string();

    coded.retain(|c| c.is_ascii_alphanumeric());
    coded.make_ascii_lowercase();

    let coded_no_spacing = String::from_utf8(
        coded
            .bytes()
            .map(|c| {
                if c.is_ascii_alphabetic() {
                    122 - c + 97
                } else {
                    c
                }
            })
            .collect(),
    )
    .unwrap();

    spacer(coded_no_spacing)
}

/// "Decipher" with the Atbash cipher.
pub fn decode(cipher: &str) -> String {
    let mut out = encode(cipher);
    out.retain(|c| c.is_ascii_alphanumeric());
    out
}

fn spacer(coded_no_spacing: String) -> String {
    let mut coded_no_spacing = coded_no_spacing.chars();

    let mut temp_char = coded_no_spacing.next();
    let mut counter = 0;
    let mut coded_with_spaces = "".to_string();
    while temp_char.is_some() {
        if counter % 5 == 0 && counter != 0 {
            coded_with_spaces.push(' ');
        }
        coded_with_spaces.push(temp_char.unwrap());
        temp_char = coded_no_spacing.next();
        counter += 1;
    }
    coded_with_spaces
}
```

Comment: This is possibly more appropriate to post as codereview.stackexchange.com or users.rust-lang.org, if your code does actually work; or to narrow down to the concrete problem, if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Is it inappropriate to post this here? I am pretty new and not sure about norms for stackoverflow. Is there a way for me to delete the question?

Comment: I've flagged it as "opinion-based", hope that the moderator would come to decide. But yes, StackOverflow is the place to ask if something doesn't work as expected. If all does work, but you wonder if it could done better, this question would be offtopic. Personally, I'd advise to go to the Rust forum mentioned in the previous comment - from my own experience, such questions are usually welcome there.

Answer (score 0):

So this was the wrong place to post this kind of thing, but in case any other exercism students find this with a google search, I want to point to the good advice given on users.rustlang.org.

I made a similar post and the people there made some [really good suggestions](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/good-needs-work-atbash-cipher-for-exercism/33839).